# Resolving ALL maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I've got big `pom.xml` with tons of dependencies and properties very often set to `RELEASE` or `LATEST`. I clean up my **.m2/** directory and execute a
 "`mvn -U clean install`" command [successfully] and I got a certain number of artifacts with the relative version.

If I try and execute the "`mvn dependency:resolve`" plugin
not all the dependencies are listed. A small number of `artifacts` is not present in the report.

How can I get the complete list of dependencies resolved using the plugin?

Comment: Which Maven Version and which version of maven-dependency-plugin do you use?

Comment: I'm using maven 3.0.5 and maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1....

Comment: The `LATEST` or `RELEASE` part for versions is not supported with Maven 3. You can use the [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)  to update to latest release etc. If you need to use LATEST i assume you should check if you could use `SNAPSHOT` versions instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding. `-Dverbose=true`

Usually, I put them into a tree as: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true`